# Refactoring problem from class to function with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am refactoring some code and now I am stuck.
The original code is from a tuto :
https://github.com/EricLondon/rails5-react-reactstrap-crud-example
All is fine there.
I try to use hooks new feature.
The new code I wrote just fail.

"Original code" is ok tested
"new code" fails

```
//"New code"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, Row, Col, Alert } from 'reactstrap'
import PostsTable from '../PostsTable'

const Api = require('../../api/Api.js')

export default function Posts() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)

  useEffect( () => {
    Api.getPosts()
      .then( response => {
        const [errata, data] = response
        if (errata) {
          setIsLoaded(true)
          setPosts([])
          setError(data)
        } else {
          setIsLoaded(true)
          setPosts(data)
        }
      })
  })

  if (error) {

    return (
      <Alert color="danger">
          Error: {error}
      </Alert>
    )

  } else if (!isLoaded) {

    return (
      <Alert color="primary">
          Loading...
      </Alert>
    )

  } else {

    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <PostsTable posts={posts}></PostsTable>
            <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts/new">Add Post</Link>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )

  }
}



//"Original code"
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Container, Row, Col, Alert } from 'reactstrap'
import PostsTable from '../PostsTable'

const Api = require('../../api/Api.js')

class Posts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      error: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Api.getPosts()
      .then(response => {
        const [error, data] = response
        if (error) {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            posts: [],
            error: data
          })
        } else {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            posts: data
          })
        }
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, posts } = this.state

    if (error) {

      return (
        <Alert color="danger">
          Error: {error}
        </Alert>
      )

    } else if (!isLoaded) {

      return (
        <Alert color="primary">
          Loading...
        </Alert>
      )

    } else {

      return (
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <PostsTable posts={posts}></PostsTable>
              <Link className="btn btn-primary" to="/posts/new">Add Post</Link>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      )

    }

  }
}

export default Posts
```

With "new code" my backend server is driving crazy:
....
Started GET "/api/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-05-26 20:45:39 +0200
Processing by Api::PostsController#index as HTML
  Post Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/controllers/api/posts_controller.rb:5
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
....
etc.

Comment: you should pass an empty to `useEffect` in order to load the posts only once : `useEffect(() => {Api.getPosts()...}, [])`

Comment: Thx I did !! It stopped the backend messages. I can post data but nothing is showed. That means problem is not solved....

Comment: can you add `console.log(data)` in the promise success handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is solved. Thx all.
In fact we wer facing 2 problems at the same time.
1/ [] in second argument was necessary,
2/ then as @olivier said there was some bad code in the child component: PostsTable.
"original code":

```
class PostsTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      posts: props.posts
    }
  }

  render() {
    const posts = this.state.posts
    if (posts.length === 0) {
      return <div></div> ......
```

I did this :
"New code":

```
class PostsTable extends Component {

  render() {
    const posts = this.props.posts
    if (posts.length === 0) {
      return <div></div> .....
```

I just render PostsTable with props only. PostsTable is now stateless.
Nota: in the original code from Eric London I think PostsTable object was **created** efrom within the global set State.
Using useEffect and setIsLoaded(true); setPosts(data) is more tricky since as soon as setIsLoaded(true) is lauched PostsTable object is created and rendering without calling constructor again.

I ending refactoring like this :

```
export default function PostsTable(props)  {
  const posts = props.posts
  if (posts.length === 0) {
    return <div></div> ....
```

thx @olivier

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `useEffect is running on every render. You should add an empty array as the 2nd argument to only run on mount:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, []);
```

By providing an array as the 2nd argument, you're telling the `useEffect` function "Run again any time one of these values changes." If you don't provide an array at all, it will run every time the component renders (in this case, any time `setIsLoading`, `setError`, or `setPosts` is called).

Giving it an empty dependency array still tells the function "run anytime one of these values changes," but because there are no values that will change, it will only run once.

Comment: Sorry but empty array is not correct. You can read this 49 minute article by Dan Abramov (creator of Redux and React Hooks) on why that is. https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: I love that article... but in this case, an empty array is correct, since they only want to fetch once on mount. See the "Moving Functions inside Effects" section of that article, it's similar to what Magnifico is doing here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#moving-functions-inside-effects

Answer (score 0):

By default, the function passed to use Effect will be executed after each render of the component.

As you are updating a state variable inside your effect, it will trigger a re-render of your component, then the effect will be executed another time, basically you have an  an infinite loop.

If you pass an empty array to `useEffect`, you will execute the effect only once as it will be re-executed only if one value in the array has changed.

The following code should solve the problem

```
useEffect( () => {
  Api.getPosts()
    .then( response => {
      const [errata, data] = response
      if (errata) {
        setIsLoaded(true)
        setPosts([])
        setError(data)
      } else {
        setIsLoaded(true)
        setPosts(data)
      }
  })
}, [])
```

Comment: I did this as you told me (first time). It changes the behavior. But it does notwork since I can't see the datas in the browser. I can add data but nothing is showed.

Comment: And I wrote: console.log(posts) after useEffect bloc and I can see all the rows of data in the console. weird

Comment: I saw on the github code that the `PostsTable` https://github.com/EricLondon/rails5-react-reactstrap-crud-example/blob/master/frontend/src/PostsTable.jsx initiate a state from the props but it never update the state when the props change, maybe replacing `setIsLoaded(true); setPosts(data)` by `setPosts(data); setIsLoaded(true)` would solve the problem

Comment: Sorry but empty array is not correct. You can read this 49 minute article by Dan Abramov (creator of Redux and React Hooks) on why that is. overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect

Comment: Olivier is right - `PostsTable` won't update when passed new props... try conditionally rendering `PostsData` based on `posts.length`, something like: `{postsData.length && <PostTable posts={posts} />}`

Comment: @olivier : j'ai fait ce que tu as dit et....ça marche !! It works I replaced setIsLoaded(true); setPosts(data) by setPosts(data); setIsLoaded(true). Now I am trying to understand why the order is so important...

Comment: the setter are **asynchronous**, so when `setIsLoaded(true)` is called it will render the code with `PostsTable` first (with an empty array for the posts property) then it will populate the posts with the data coming from the API (coming from `setPosts(data))`. It will re-render the component `PostTable` with an array (not empty). As `Postable` doesn't update its state when passing new props, the state posts array stay empty (its initial value)

Comment: maybe the good policy is to render a component with the props passed by parent and the states calculated out of the constructor

Comment: in this example, I don't see the benefit of using a `state` in the `PostTable` component, it would be better to directly use the `posts` property

Comment: That is what I did then ! see first answer of this post

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect( () => {
    Api.getPosts()
      .then( response => {
        const [errata, data] = response
        if (errata) {
          setIsLoaded(true)
          setPosts([])
          setError(data)
          console.log('-+- showing data1 -+-')
          console.log(data)
        } else {
          setIsLoaded(true)
          setPosts(data)
          console.log('-+- showing data2 -+-')
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
  },[])
```

That shows '-+- showing data2 -+- with 
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 14, title: "qsdf", body: "qsdf", created_at: "2019-05-26T13:07:58.006Z", updated_at: "2019-05-26T13:07:58.006Z"}1: {id: 15, title: "qsdf", body: "egg", created_at: "2019-05-26T17:47:48.323Z", updated_at: "2019-05-26T17:47:48.323Z"}2: {id: 16, title: "qdf", body: "qdf", created_at: "2019-05-26T17:48:52.257Z", updated_at: "2019-05-26T17:48:52.257Z"}3: {id: 17, title: "qsdf", body: "h", created_at: "2019-05-26T19:49:41.108Z", updated_at: "2019-05-26T19:49:41.108Z"}4: {id: 18, title: "qsdf", body: "123", created_at: "2019-05-26T19:59:38.002Z", updated_at: "2019-05-26T19:59:38.002Z"}length: 5__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to other answers but empty array is not correct. You can read this 49 minute article by Dan Abramov (creator of Redux and React Hooks) on why that is.

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

I believe you can solve your problem by combining all your useState hooks like so:

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({posts: [],
                                      isLoaded: false,
                                      error: null })


  useEffect( () => {
    Api.getPosts()
      .then( response => {
        const [errata, data] = response
        if (errata) {
          setState({ ...state, 
                     isLoaded: true, 
                     posts: [],
                     error: data })
        } else {
          setState({ ...state, 
                     isLoaded: true, 
                     posts: [data],
                     error: null })
        }
      })
  }, [state.isLoaded] )
```

make sure you pass in the previous state with the spread syntax otherwise your previous state will not be saved.

Alternate way use a conditional in the useEffect and pass in the entire state as a dependency to useEffect

```
export default function Posts() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({posts: [],
                                      isLoaded: false,
                                      error: null })


  useEffect( () => {
  if(!state.isLoaded) {
    Api.getPosts()
      .then( response => {
        const [errata, data] = response
        if (errata) {
          setState({ ...state, 
                     isLoaded: true, 
                     posts: [],
                     error: data })
        } else {
          setState({ ...state, 
                     isLoaded: true, 
                     posts: [data],
                     error: null })
        }
      })
    }
  }, [state] )
```

Comment: The article you linked to is fantastic, I've read it before... but in this case an empty array is correct, since `getPosts()` isn't dependent on any variables (only fetch on mount). If it took a param (url/query/etc), they should include the param in the deps array (fetch again on param change). They should _not_ pass `loading` into the dependency array, that will trigger a render loop when `getPosts` calls back. They _definitely_ shouldn't use the 2nd method, that's the same as if they didn't have an array at all.

Comment: See this section in the article you linked to, it's similar to what @Magnifico is doing here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#moving-functions-inside-effects (specifically "deps are ok" for the empty array)

Comment: Nope this is incorrect, In this section he quite literally says empty array is not the best way to make API requests with useEffect()                         https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#dont-lie-to-react-about-dependencies

Comment: The case he's describing (where you shouldn't use an empty array) is specifically when the fetch function is defined inside the component but outside `useEffect`.